# Using collection within SELECT in IN condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle11gr2

I have code using locally defined collection:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WBAR_COUNT_TEST(IB_TAKE_WAITING IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
                                            IB_TAKE_ERROR   IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
                                            IB_TAKE_KILLED  IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
                                            IB_TAKE_SUCCESS IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE)
   RETURN PLS_INTEGER IS
   SUBTYPE ST_JOB_STATUS IS JOB_STATUS_HISTORY.STATUS%TYPE;
   TYPE TTV_STATUSES IS TABLE OF ST_JOB_STATUS;
   LTV_STATUSES   TTV_STATUSES := TTV_STATUSES();
   LN_RETURN_CODE PLS_INTEGER := 0;
   PROCEDURE ADD_STATUS(IB_FLAG   IN BOOLEAN,
                        IV_STATUS IN ST_JOB_STATUS) IS
   BEGIN
     IF IB_FLAG THEN
       LTV_STATUSES.EXTEND;
       LTV_STATUSES(LTV_STATUSES.LAST) := IV_STATUS;
     END IF;
   END ADD_STATUS;
 BEGIN
   ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_WAITING, 'WAITING');
   ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_ERROR, 'ERROR');
   ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_KILLED, 'KILLED');
   ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_SUCCESS, 'SUCCESS');
   SELECT COUNT(1)
     INTO LN_RETURN_CODE
     FROM JOB_STATUS_HISTORY H
    WHERE H.STATUS IN (LTV_STATUSES);

   RETURN LN_RETURN_CODE;
 END WBAR_COUNT_TEST;
```

I receiving: `PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements`

Is there any way to walk-around defining `TTV_STATUSES` as global type in `Oracle 11g R2`?

Comment: Currently I've decide to define global type and changed `WHERE H.STATUS IN (LTV_STATUSES)` to `WHERE H.STATUS member of LTV_STATUSES`

Comment: This will help you : https://forums.oracle.com/message/3631138#3631138

Comment: `WHERE H.STATUS IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(CAST(LTV_STATUSES AS TTV_STATUSES)))` works 16 times faster! :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have trivialized this example, I wouldn't bother with the overhead of creating local types, and just use Dynamic SQL.  This particular example is pretty safe, as you are in control of the text that gets inserted, and given thee limit of 4 variables, you have a maximum of 15 queries stored in the cache, so not a big deal there either:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION WBAR_COUNT_TEST(IB_TAKE_WAITING IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
                                        IB_TAKE_ERROR   IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
                                        IB_TAKE_KILLED  IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE,
                                        IB_TAKE_SUCCESS IN BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE)
  RETURN PLS_INTEGER IS
  -- Character String large enough to hold maximum string length
  LTV_STATUSES VARCHAR2(40) := NULL;
  LN_RETURN_CODE PLS_INTEGER := 0;
  PROCEDURE ADD_STATUS(IB_FLAG   IN BOOLEAN,
                       IV_STATUS IN ST_JOB_STATUS) IS
  BEGIN
    IF IB_FLAG THEN
      -- Concatenate desired values togather in IN-LIST format
      IF LTV_STATUSES IS NULL THEN
        LTV_STATUSES := ''''||IV_STATUS||'''';
      ELSE
        LTV_STATUSES := ','''||IV_STATUS||'''';
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END ADD_STATUS;
BEGIN
  ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_WAITING, 'WAITING');
  ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_ERROR, 'ERROR');
  ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_KILLED, 'KILLED');
  ADD_STATUS(IB_TAKE_SUCCESS, 'SUCCESS');
  -- Makes sure we don't try and run the query with NO values selected
  IF LTV_STATUSES IS NOT NULL THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM JOB_STATUS_HISTORY H WHERE H.STATUS in ('||LTV_STATUSES||')' into LN_RETURN_CODE;
  END IF;  

  RETURN LN_RETURN_CODE;
END WBAR_COUNT_TEST;
```